# Select maximum of a count in a grouped clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-5.7

I have the following tables:

```
Vehicles(v͟i͟n͟, model,category)
Sales(s͟a͟l͟e͟I͟D͟, staffID,customerID,date)
vehicleSold(saleID,v͟i͟n͟,salePrice)
```

When I join these tables using:

```
select YEAR(Sales.saleDate)
     , Vehicles.model
     , count(Vehicles.model) 'Sold'
     , Vehicles.category
  from Vehicles 
  JOIN vehicleSold
    on Vehicles.vin = vehicleSold.vin
  JOIN Sales 
    on Sales.saleID = vehicleSold.saleID
 group 
    by YEAR(Sales.saleDate)
     , Vehicles.model
     , Vehicles.category;
```

Result is:

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+----------------+
| YEAR(Sales.saleDate) | model       | Sold | category       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+----------------+
|                 2020 | Altima      |    1 | car            |
|                 2020 | Flying Spur |    2 | car            |
|                 2020 | Lifan E3    |    3 | Electric Moped |
|                 2020 | Ridgeline   |    2 | truck          |
|                 2020 | Shiver      |    4 | motorbike      |
+----------------------+-------------+------+----------------+
```

Out of this table I want to get the model that was most sold in a category. So, in this case I only want to return a 2020, Flying Spur, car as the only row in category car because it was the most sold in 2020 in its category. I tried using a subquery is MAX(COUNT(*)) but I guess that is not supported in mysql. If anyone could point out my mistake and has any idea how to do this then that would be big help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What version of MySQL? Version 8 or later has features to solve this easily, prior versions need a different approach. Please always specify your dbms version.

Comment: what happens if Altima also sold 2 in 2020? i.e. **what happens if there is more than one row with the most sold in a year?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use MySQL version 8 or later that supports `row_number()` or `rank()` you could use one of these windowing functions

If you must only have one row per category, then use `row_number()` or if you want to include any models that are tied in top spot use `rank()` like this

```
select Yr
     , model
     , Sold
     , ctegory
from (
    select YEAR(Sales.saleDate) Yr
         , Vehicles.model
         , count(Vehicles.model) 'Sold'
         , Vehicles.category
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Sales.saleDate), category 
                             ORDER BY sold DESC)
           as rn
      from Vehicles 
      JOIN vehicleSold
        on Vehicles.vin = vehicleSold.vin
      JOIN Sales 
        on Sales.saleID = vehicleSold.saleID
     group 
        by YEAR(Sales.saleDate)
         , Vehicles.model
         , Vehicles.category
    ) as d
where rn = 1
```

for rank the syntax is almost identical:

```
     , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Sales.saleDate), category 
                   ORDER BY sold DESC)
       as rnk
```

Notes:

1. When used with group by these windowing functions are performed after the group by has been performed.
2. if you don't have MySQL 8 or later please remember to tell inform us of your db version in the question so proposed solutions are more useful to you

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54059cb2c7a6556fc35dbed45b7ed1db)*

Comment: So sorry but I don't use version 8 Im using an older version for learning purposes. Version 5.7. If you let me know how to do this in this version that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

For versions of MySQL prior to 8 (where `row_number()` is not available) there is a method that mimics `row_number()` which in practice is workable but is considered something of a "hack" by some.

It works by using a subquery which is **must employ an** `order by` clause and this ordering will allow us to determine when to assign 1 to each "grouping" of the data. Here I have concatenated the year and category for the "groups", if that concatenation is the same as a previous row the the row number increments, if the concatenation is different to the previous row we get a row number of 1. This logic is performed by the `IF()` function seen below

```
SELECT
      yr
    , model
    , sold
    , category
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=concat(yr, category),@row_num + 1, 1) AS rn
        , yr
        , model
        , sold
        , category
        , @prev_value := concat(yr, category)
    FROM mytable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
    ORDER BY
            yr
          , category
          , sold DESC
    ) as d
WHERE rn = 1
```

With a bit more trickery we can extend that row_number simulation to rank simulation as well so that ties at top position will be returned:

```
SELECT
      yr
    , model
    , sold
    , category
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=concat(yr, category)
                        , IF(@sold = sold, @row_num, @row_num + 1)
                    , 1) AS rnk
        , yr
        , model
        , sold
        , category
        , @prev_value := concat(yr, category)
        , @sold := sold
    FROM mytable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='', @sold := 1) vars
    ORDER BY
            yr
          , category
          , sold DESC
    ) as d
WHERE rnk = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54059cb2c7a6556fc35dbed45b7ed1db)*